Why does a write back cache does not lead to less conflict misses compared to a write through cache?
The correct answer was less total amount of memory transferred which I'm also confused about. What if the program dealt with memory that was not nearby and therefore writeback caches took in more data than necessary.
My thinking was that write back caches bring in the whole chunk of memory, which causes less misses.
the question

does not lead to less = leads to more?  is that what you are asking.  write back leads to more misses?

no matter what, cache or not, write through or not, etc.  There is always a situation that will make it slow or slower than not having that feature.  So there are many what ifs.  Your question has huge gaps in context that you didnt share...

what does this have to do with arm?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
